# How to test a chatting application using appium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, chat, appium

I have to create a framework to test an android chatting application. I am planning to use Appium with Java. I am unable to figure out the test setup, whether I have to use two android devices, or two separate projects for Client A and B or maybe something else.

Answer (score 2):

I may suggest following strategy:

1. User 1 is **simulated on device** (use Appium)
2. User 2, 3, etc. are **simulated via API of your application**

Benefits:

1. Easy setup: single appium session with one device.
   If you go with 2 users/2 devices you most likely have a separate session for each device = more complex
2. More robust and faster tests: the less UI interactions you do, the more robust maintainable solution you have
3. It is still an e2e test: all the UI verifications you do with User 1, but all the setup and preconditions you handle via API.

Comment: It's a valid approach for an integration test. Though, it no longer qualify as an e2e test.

Comment: Disagree. It will be a valid e2e test in terms of user 1: there is no different to that user if other users on real devices or bots using API.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to create:
- server side (API)
- client side (Appium-java-client)

Server side
should have connection to API, and have methods You expect server/backend should interact with user.

Client side
create page-object design on Android app, and create interactions on that side like click(button), sendKeys(input text) etc.

...and introduce "3 side" tests, which will call both sides depending on interaction needed (suggest using testng)

So your test would look like:

open app. (client - Android)
input text (client)
return response (server - API)
catch response and do following interactions (client)
...
...
and so on...

So my idea would be to create inside one project 3 sides,

1. Client side (java-appium-client) + Appium server (apk),
2. Server side (whatever backend / API / REST),
3. Combined in test side (testng+java+appium+backend calls)